# Consistency strength of weakly inaccessibles without $\mathsf{GCH}$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

*This is a revised version of a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2098832/212120) on Math.SE. It is a rather basic question (which I'd be glad to delete if the community regards as off-topic).*

---

Is there a way to prove that (if consistent) $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't prove that there exists a weakly inaccessible without first showing that $\mathsf{GCH}$ is relatively consistent? Obviously, if we can show that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove the *consistency* of a  weakly inaccessible is much better.

It would be a little bit surprising if there are no proofs without the full logical apparatus of definability that involves $V=L$. Perhaps some wise trick using reflection might do it, but it is just a guess.

Two weakened version of the same question are also interesting to me:

1. Showing strength of weakly Mahlo cardinals with the same restrictions;
2. Same questions, using at most the consistency of $\mathsf{CH}$.

The only really similar question on Math.SE I found is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162740/212120), and I wasn't much too thorough in my web search because I'm pretty sure that this is just a curiosity.

**PS.** Answers using Easton magic are not allowed!

Comment: How do you even prove $V\neq L$ is consistent without "Easton magic"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps you didn't understand my jokingly comment. You can do that with the simplest Cohen forcing; I was referring to the fact that you can force $\mathsf{GCH}$, and I believe (though I'm not sure in this one) that this proof avoids $L$. I'm looking for something along the lines "$V_\kappa\models \mathsf{ZFC}$" which (by Gödel's Second) gives the result for strongly inaccessibles.

Comment: If you only have one inaccessible cardinal, add $\kappa^+$ Cohen reals, then it is weakly inaccessible, and you cannot force back GCH while preserving it. The forcing that restores GCH will invariably collapse cardinals when and where it needs to.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you very much for this piece of information. In any case, I don't know what is the connection to the question, or to the fact that (having an inaccessible or not) $V\neq L$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The point is that if you have a weakly inaccessible cardinal (which is not strongly inaccessible), then the only way to "carve out of $V_\kappa$ a model of ZFC" is to look at something like $L_\kappa$. Any other reasonable situation that you are trying to achieve will already include a "too large power set" and you will have a failure of Replacement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, your second comment was a response to my (not fruitful) "suggestion". Thank you very much, and if you have any ideas apart from this $V_\kappa$ thing that could work (or why it couldn't), please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible. Then it is immediate $L_\kappa$ satisfies pairing, separation, extensionality, regularity, infinity, union, and choice. To see that $L_\kappa$ satisfies Replacement, let $h(x)=min\{\alpha|x\subseteq L_\alpha\}$. Let $X\in L_\kappa$,  and $F(X)=\{f(x)|x\in X\}$. Let $Z=\{h(x)|x\in F(X)\}$. Such a set exists as $F(X)\subseteq L_\kappa$. Then let $\lambda$ be the order type of $Z$, and $\eta_{\alpha+1}=min\{\beta>\eta_\alpha|\beta\in Z\}$ be continuous at limits, with $\eta_0=min\,Z$. Then if $Z$ is bounded in $\kappa$, it is clear $F(X)\in L_\kappa$. Else $\kappa=\lim_{\alpha\to \lambda}\eta_\alpha$, yet $\lambda<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ is regular. Contradiction.

Now it remains to show that $L_\kappa$ satisfies power set. Let $Y\subseteq X$. Then $L_\kappa\vDash \exists\delta>|Y|(\delta\text{ is a limit}\ \land\  Y\in L_\delta)$. Let $L_\kappa\vDash M\prec L_\delta$, and $|M|=|Y|$. Then take the transitive collapse $\pi(M)$ and so there is some limit ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\pi(Y)=Y$ and $Y\in L_\gamma$. Hence $L_\kappa\vDash ZFC$, and so we cannot prove the consistency of "There exists a weakly inaccessible cardinal" from $ZFC$. This argument does indeed skirt very close to the argument that $V=L\rightarrow GCH$, yet does not quite prove it. The rest follows from every weakly Mahlo cardinal being weakly inaccessible.

**Edit:** If you want to avoid the $L$ construction all together, then I suggest we construct a new cumulative hierarchy. We want $W_\alpha$ to be sufficiently large to contain pairing, separation, etc. So, we want $L_\alpha\subseteq W_\alpha$. We also want it satisfy the condensation lemma so we need $W_\alpha=\cup_{\beta<\alpha}W_\beta^{W_\alpha}$.

Let $W_{\alpha+1}=\{x\subseteq W_\alpha\mid\text{$\phi(x,p_0...p_n)^{W_\alpha}$ is a definition for $x,p_0...p_n\in W_\alpha$}\}$. If $x=\{y|\phi(x,p_0...p_n)^{W_\alpha}\}$, then $\forall y\in W_\alpha(y\in x\leftrightarrow \phi(x,p_0...p_n)^{W_\alpha})$ is a definition for $x$, and so $L_\alpha\subseteq W_\alpha$. Conversely, as $W_\alpha$ is transitive $\phi(x,p_0...p_n)^{{W_\beta}^{W_\alpha}}\leftrightarrow \phi(x,p_0...p_n)^{W_\beta}$ whenever $W_\beta\in W_\alpha$, and so $W_\alpha=\cup_{\beta<\alpha}W_\beta^{W_\alpha}$.

From here, simply repeat the argument from before.

Comment: By the fact $|L_\kappa|=\kappa$, $|F(X)|<\kappa$, and $|\lambda|=|F(X)|$, and so $\lambda<\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Though perhaps not obvious from my wording, I am looking for proofs that avoid using the constructible hierarchy. Nevertheless, I need to read your answer in detail, still.

Comment: I reworked my answer, perhaps it is better now?